# Expectations of a Poisson random variable with its mean containing two same Poisson random variables.

Tags: probability

$X^2_0 \sim Poisson(\lambda T)$, $X^1_0 \sim Poisson(\lambda T)$, $X^2_1 \sim Poisson(\lambda(T+\alpha X^2_0 -\alpha X^1_0))$ with $\alpha, T, \lambda$ being constants. $X^2_0, X^1_0$ are independent of each other.

I want to find E($X^2_1$). I have two choices, but I am not sure which one is correct?

The first choice is: since $X^2_0$ and $X^1_0$ have the same distribution, $X^2_0 \sim Poisson(\lambda T)$, so $E(X^2_1)=\lambda T$.

The second choice is $E(X^2_1)=E(E(X^2_1 \mid X^2_0=x, X^1_0=y))$

Comment: In the notation $X_0^2$ is $2$ an exponent or an index? If it is an index then the notation is confusing and IMV you can better write something like $X_{0,1},X_{0,2}$.

Comment: They are notations, sry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, of course they are notations but what I am asking is: do they denote powers?

Comment: They are the name of the random variable, but not powers

Comment: What if $T+\alpha X_0^2-\alpha X_0^1$ takes a negative value? Then the parameter of the distribution of $X_1^2$ will be negative but that is not possible for Poisson distribution.

Comment: As @drhab pointed out, $X_1^2$ does not have Poisson distribution, because $\mathbb P(\lambda(T + \alpha X_0^2 - \alpha X_0^1) < 0) > 0$.